# How to consume API call that returns FileContentResult programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient, filecontentresult

I'm trying to consume an API that my team created that returns a `FileContentResult` (a PDF File) for mobile.

I have written some code to retrieve the byte array of that result as shown below.

Line that returns PDF file in the API:

```
return new FileContentResult(result.Data.Data, "application/pdf");
```

My code:

```
public class QuoteCoreService : BaseService, IQuoteCoreService
    {
        public QuoteCoreService(IService<CollaborationClient> httpClient, IAuthenticationService authenticationService) : base(httpClient, authenticationService)
        {
        }

        public byte[] GetSampleTag(string QuoteId)
        {
            var headers = BuildHeaders();
            byte[] result;
            try
            {
                result = _httpClient.Get<byte[]>("SampleTagUpdate/PDFFile/" + QuoteId, headers).Result;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(e, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "GetSampleTag()", "HTTP Call to service" } });
                result = null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

`IService<CollaborationClient>` is just HttpClient with some basic configs added in the background. I expect `_httpClient.Get` line to return a byte array.

Comment: you want to get the FileContents property of the return object - that is the byte[] that represents the file data.

Comment: I dont follow. Is that what im doing when I'm writing <byte[]>

Comment: no, you are taking the ENTIRE return object as a byte[].  Presumably the return object is json, so you should be able to deserialize it and extract just the FileContents